# Post ownership of an item appearing in Low Quality Posts Review queue

Tags: discussion

I was working through the Ask Different, [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts). Per my experience, I understand that most posts end up getting a delete vote and gets deleted eventually.

I understand (please correct me in the answer if I am wrong), that posts here end up after getting flagged either as *low quality* or *not an answer* (are there any other ways for a post to end up here?).

I am just curious to know, if it is technically possible for my own post to end up under *my* Low Quality Posts review queue, to be reviewed by me?

I think it would not (by the way how the site is programmed), as I may not make a rational decision is such cases.

Is there any backing reference in support/denial of this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to review your own Low Quality Posts, just like you can't review your own questions in the Close and Reopen Votes review queues. The latter two cases have I tested on Meta Stack Exchange, specifically for the Low Quality Posts queue I have to dig a little further but I'm sure one of the regulars would've noticed it.

> I understand (please correct me in the answer if I am wrong), that posts here end up after getting flagged either as *low quality* or *not an answer* (are there any other ways for a post to end up here?).

That's correct; they only end up there after being flagged as Very Low Quality or Not An Answer, but some of those VLQ flags are cast automatically by the system. A post cannot enter the queue twice, and there are probably more exceptions.

Some references on mother Meta:

- [What exactly does a VLQ flag do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181796/295232)
- [Can flags send a post into the Low Quality Posts review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/295232)